# Improving SVG animation performance with nested groups

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, svg

I am building a visualization using SVG elements.
I'm having some performance issues and I'm wondering if there's anything I could do to speed up the rendering?

What I want to draw initially is several rows (~10) of grouped symbols (~15-25 per row):

```
<g class="row">
  <g class="symbol">
    <path class="fill" d="..." />
    <path class="fill" d="..." />
    <path class="fill" d="..." />
  </g>
  <g class="symbol">
    <path class="fill" d="..." />
    <path class="fill" d="..." />
    <path class="fill" d="..." />
  </g>
  <g class="symbol">
    <path class="fill" d="..." />
    <path class="fill" d="..." />
    <path class="fill" d="..." />
  </g>
</g>
[another row ...]
```

When dragging a timeslider I'd like to move the rows vertically and add / remove symbols from the various row groups.

Is there a way to, for example, reference 1 "svg:g symbol" and clone that one instead of redrawing the path data? Or are there other optimizations that can be made?

Answer (score 0):

There is an `use` element `<use href="#idofyourclonegroup">...`
so you can give the `<g class="symbol">...` an id like `<g class="symbol" id="g1">...`,
and when you add another one `...` add an `use` element like this:

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

var use = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'use');
use.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, 'href', '#g1');

[someparentelement].appendChild(use);
```